# How do I make my bot create a role when it is added to a guild?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is the code I am using for my bot to add roles as soon as its added to a server:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const Event = require("../Structures/Events")




module.exports = new Event("guildCreate", guild =>{



    guild.roles.edit(guild.id, {hoist: false,
mentionable: false,
permissions: []},   )

    guild.roles.create({ THE ROLES DATA })
```

AND THIS IS MY EVENT HANDLER

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")

const Client = require ("./Client.js")

/**
 * 
 * @param {Client} client 
 * @param  {Discord.ClientEvents[K]} eventArgs 
 */
function runFunction(client, ...eventArgs){}
/**
 * @template {key of Discord.ClientEvents} K
 */
class Event {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {K} event 
     * @param {runFunction<K>} runFunction 
     */
    constructor(event, runFunction){
        this.event = event
        this.run = runFunction
    }
}

module.exports = Event
```

Now whenever I try to compile this with "node ." this gives the error that guild is not defined what exactly am I doing wrong here? shouldn't guild be defined by the event?

Comment: Verify that your handler passes the event Listener's parameters properly. I still don't understand why you're choosing to create a wrapper for the events when the `client'`s event emitter works straight out of the box, but regardless do some debugging of your `Event` class

Comment: I fixed it thnx, using client's event emitter out of the box creates a mess nothing is organized and slows down stuff too

Comment: It's not much different than your wrapper, check out the [Event Handler Guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's some missing code here...but you have some basic pieces.  First You need something to load all the events.  Second you need an event handler that calls when an event is detected.  Third you need the event itself.  I think you're trying to create a new object (constructor) when an event happens....I think you want an event handler function, and then potentially call a class constructor if required...but I am not sure without more code.  Example handler, which is where I think you should start:

```
bot.on("guildCreate", guild => {
     // do your roles stuff here
})
```

you can also do it function style:
in guildCreate.mjs (my example, the event handler calls events which I loaded, based on the file name.  so this is event handler for when bot joins a server, the guildCreate event occurs.)

```
// note this function can be called anything, but the important part is to export it 'as default'
// this allows the 'default' to match the file name.  the event handler cares totally about the file name to capture the
// event intended, in this case adding the bot to a new server.
async function guildAdd(guild) {

    const bot = this;
    // do your roles stuff
}
export { guildAdd as default };
```